# Count of API Daily limits on different family sites

Tags: discussion

> API daily limits:
>
> - Key: 10,000
> - No Key: 300

How these caps are calculated daily, hitting different family sites?

> 300/10,000 requests on Stack Overflow
>   +
>   300/10,000 requests on Super User
>   +
>   300/10,000 requests on Server Fault

**OR**

> 300/10,000 requests on Stack Overflow - Super User - Server Fault

Comment: Justin has the answer, but see also: http://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is per site.  See [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work) question.

> These limit are per-site, per-day. So, with a legitimate key, you can make 10,000 requests a day to each site which exposes the API.