# Update the default filter editor to use the API key

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, api-v2, filter

When I run a sample query using the SE API browser (is that right term?), say against `/questions` for example ([here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)), I'll always see something to the effect of:

```
...
  "quota_remaining": 9424,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": true
}
```

Which tells me it's using a key and is *not* restricted by the [300 quota limit](https://stackapps.com/q/67/9533). A quick check through the Chrome debugger (or firebug) will reveal that the key it's using is `key=U4DMV...`.

Now when I go to **edit** the default filter using:

[image: scr1]

And upon hitting `save`, I'm presented with the following:

[image: scr2]

And investigating this further in the Chrome debugger reveals:

```
{
  "error_id" :502,
  "error_name": "throttle_violation",
  "error_message": "too many requests from this IP, more requests availabe in 27628 seconds"
}
```

So basically what's happening here is that all queries generated when hitting the `Run` button use a key and are therefore *not* restricted to the 300 limit, whereas, the query used to *build* the filter doesn't use the said key (and *is* restricted). **Would it be possible to update the *filter builder* to use the key as well?**

Before someone points me to use [/filters/create](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) instead, I should mention that it doesn't appear to work for *uber* filters for whatever reason. Let me demonstrate:

Create a [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) with the following parameters:

**include**:

```
.backoff;.error_id;.error_message;.error_name;.has_more;.items;question.accepted_answer_id;question.answer_count;question.body;question.bounty_amount;question.bounty_closes_date;question.closed_date;question.closed_reason;question.community_owned_date;question.creation_date;question.down_vote_count;question.favorite_count;question.is_answered;question.last_activity_date;question.last_edit_date;question.link;question.locked_date;question.migrated_from;question.migrated_to;question.owner;question.protected_date;question.question_id;question.score;question.tags;question.title;question.up_vote_count;question.view_count;access_token.access_token;access_token.account_id;access_token.expires_on_date;access_token.scope;badge.award_count;badge.badge_id;badge.badge_type;badge.link;badge.name;badge.rank;badge.user;badge_count.bronze;badge_count.gold;badge_count.silver;error.description;error.error_id;error.error_name;event.creation_date;event.event_id;event.event_type;filter.filter;filter.filter_type;filter.included_fields;inbox_item.answer_id;inbox_item.comment_id;inbox_item.creation_date;inbox_item.is_unread;inbox_item.item_type;inbox_item.link;inbox_item.question_id;inbox_item.site;inbox_item.title;info.answers_per_minute;info.api_revision;info.badges_per_minute;info.new_active_users;info.questions_per_minute;info.total_accepted;info.total_answers;info.total_badges;info.total_comments;info.total_questions;info.total_unanswered;info.total_users;info.total_votes;network_user.account_id;network_user.answer_count;network_user.badge_counts;network_user.creation_date;network_user.last_access_date;network_user.question_count;network_user.reputation;network_user.site_name;network_user.site_url;network_user.user_id;post.creation_date;post.last_activity_date;post.last_edit_date;post.owner;post.post_id;post.post_type;post.score;privilege.description;privilege.reputation;privilege.short_description;question_timeline.comment_id;question_timeline.creation_date;question_timeline.down_vote_count;question_timeline.owner;question_timeline.post_id;question_timeline.question_id;question_timeline.revision_guid;question_timeline.timeline_type;question_timeline.up_vote_count;question_timeline.user;reputation.on_date;reputation.post_id;reputation.post_type;reputation.reputation_change;reputation.user_id;reputation.vote_type;revision.comment;revision.creation_date;revision.is_rollback;revision.last_tags;revision.last_title;revision.post_id;revision.post_type;revision.revision_guid;revision.revision_number;revision.revision_type;revision.set_community_wiki;revision.tags;revision.title;revision.user;suggested_edit.approval_date;suggested_edit.comment;suggested_edit.creation_date;suggested_edit.post_id;suggested_edit.post_type;suggested_edit.proposing_user;suggested_edit.rejection_date;suggested_edit.suggested_edit_id;suggested_edit.tags;suggested_edit.title;tag.count;tag.has_synonyms;tag.is_moderator_only;tag.is_required;tag.name;tag.user_id;tag_score.post_count;tag_score.score;tag_score.user;tag_synonym.applied_count;tag_synonym.creation_date;tag_synonym.from_tag;tag_synonym.last_applied_date;tag_synonym.to_tag;tag_wiki.body_last_edit_date;tag_wiki.excerpt;tag_wiki.excerpt_last_edit_date;tag_wiki.tag_name;top_tag.answer_count;top_tag.answer_score;top_tag.question_count;top_tag.question_score;top_tag.tag_name;user.account_id;user.age;user.badge_counts;user.creation_date;user.display_name;user.is_employee;user.last_access_date;user.last_modified_date;user.link;user.location;user.profile_image;user.reputation;user.reputation_change_day;user.reputation_change_month;user.reputation_change_quarter;user.reputation_change_week;user.reputation_change_year;user.timed_penalty_date;user.user_id;user.user_type;user.website_url;user_timeline.badge_id;user_timeline.comment_id;user_timeline.creation_date;user_timeline.detail;user_timeline.post_id;user_timeline.post_type;user_timeline.suggested_edit_id;user_timeline.timeline_type;user_timeline.title;user_timeline.user_id
```

**exclude**:

```
answer.answer_id;answer.body;answer.comments;answer.community_owned_date;answer.creation_date;answer.down_vote_count;answer.is_accepted;answer.last_activity_date;answer.last_edit_date;answer.link;answer.locked_date;answer.owner;answer.question_id;answer.score;answer.title;answer.up_vote_count;.page;.page_size;.quota_max;.quota_remaining;.total;.type;comment.body;comment.comment_id;comment.creation_date;comment.edited;comment.link;comment.owner;comment.post_id;comment.post_type;comment.reply_to_user;comment.score;migration_info.on_date;migration_info.other_site;migration_info.question_id;question.answers;question.comments;related_site.name;related_site.relation;related_site.site_url;shallow_user.display_name;shallow_user.link;shallow_user.profile_image;shallow_user.reputation;shallow_user.user_id;shallow_user.user_type;site.aliases;site.api_site_parameter;site.audience;site.closed_beta_date;site.favicon_url;site.icon_url;site.launch_date;site.logo_url;site.markdown_extensions;site.name;site.open_beta_date;site.related_sites;site.site_state;site.site_type;site.site_url;site.styling;site.twitter_account;styling.link_color;styling.tag_background_color;styling.tag_foreground_color;badge.description;event.excerpt;event.link;inbox_item.body;info.site;network_user.user_type;post.body;post.comments;post.down_vote_count;post.up_vote_count;reputation.link;reputation.title;revision.body;revision.last_body;suggested_edit.body;tag.last_activity_date;tag_wiki.body;tag_wiki.last_body_editor;tag_wiki.last_excerpt_editor;user.about_me;user.answer_count;user.down_vote_count;user.question_count;user.up_vote_count;user.view_count;user_timeline.link
```

**unsafe**:

```
false
```

And this generates the error `Invalid JSON returned`. Inspecting this in the Chrome debugger reveals:

[image: scr3]

If you're wondering where I got the parameters for this *uber* filter, I used the *default filter editor* to select/unselect everything I needed, and sniffed out the request using the debugger.

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API console in the documentation should attach it's key to all requests now.

For the filter creation error, what's happening there is actually a size check against the incoming parameters .NET enforces.  A better error is returned now, but the proper course of action for a consumer remains the same; use POST when creating filters with a large # of includes/excludes.

POST is supported only on [filters/create](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter).  If you want to continue using GET for ease (when adhoc-ing filters in a browser, for instance), consider using the `base` parameter which lets you create a filter with a delta (oftentimes a very small delta) from an existing filter.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that took care of it. On a related note, I guess it isn't a big deal that the private `key=U4DMV...` is exposed since the restriction is IP based in any case, right?

Comment: @MarvinPinto - request keys aren't private, and yes it's because the throttle is IP based.