# I want a python program example for more requests a day

Tags: support, api, python, stackoverflow

How can I make about 10k requests on

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/+J+/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

using python program in a day. Where `J` is variable and changing over a loop.

I am trying to get text data from above link by iterating over `J` but only 300 requests are entertained a day. I want to know with an example how can I get about 10k requests a day.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code), [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api), and [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/3055/is-there-a-limit-of-api-requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subject to [throttling](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

You can get more calls by  first [registering](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) your application. After that you get access to a detail page which includes a value for `key`.  The description for that field is:

> Pass this as key when making requests against the Stack Exchange API to receive a higher request quota.
>
> This is not considered a secret, and may be safely embed in client side code or distributed binaries.

Once you have your key, the url to use becomes:

`/users/+J+/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&key=*somekey*`

I have an example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269020/158100) where I use a `key` query parameter in a similar way.

Keep in mind to still check for the existence of a value in the `backoff` field in the [wrapper response](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper). It indicates the number of seconds to wait before you are allowed to make the next call.

Comment: If this is his answer, then this question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/3055/is-there-a-limit-of-api-requests) and others.  It's a poor question, but he seems to want a *working example* in Python.

Comment: @BrockAdams not completely. Getting an access token is one way to get a higher quota. Using a `key` is a different one. That distinction is not explained in either the doc or the answer you linked to but does work as well. Maybe I found a usage scenario of `key` that wasn't supposed to work without an access_token. In that case I've found a bug.