# Why is my API quota not resetting after UTC reset?

Tags: support, bug, api, limits, quota

According to [How API Keys Work](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work), the default daily API limit -- which is per site, per day -- is 300.

I started with 300, as expected, but over a period of days, I've noticed that the remaining quota has now been whittled down to about 70 something:

```
{
"items":
    [
        { "user_id":0000,"display_name":"abc","account_id":00000 }
    ],
    "quota_remaining":70,"quota_max":300,"has_more":false
};
```

Even after the UTC reset today, the quota remaining is still the same. Is this a one time thing where when I use all of this up, that's it, I'm done for good, or is this a bug?

What's more, this doesn't in fact seem to be counting per-site, as I can change the site query parameter to any site on the network, and the count still decreases, as if this is not in fact measured per site, but instead, network-wide:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=abc&site=serverfault&filter=!*MxJcsxUhQG*kL8D&callback=test
```

As an aside, I don't believe I'll need an API key, since the app I'm building makes requests on behalf of each individual user, and since I really don't picture ever hitting the 300 daily cap since I'm caching the data in chrome.storage.local.

This assumes, of course, that the 300 cap is in fact a daily cap and not a lifetime cap. Otherwise, my users would be able to use this for a limited time, until their own lifetime quotas have been exceeded.

Is this a bug, or am I going to need to use even heavier caching, like writing data to a file on the users' filesystems? *(euuuuughh - shivers at the thought...)*

---

Two days later, I checked my quota again by hitting the API. It now says 299 out of 300, so it looks like it's been reset. It's currently Nov 8, 7:38 AM UTC, so I'll wait until it rolls over again and do another test.

---

It's now currently Nov 9, 6:25 AM UTC, and I just hit the API for the first time since my last edit, and I have 297 out of 300 remaining. Is this a bug, or does the quota not reset every 24 hours as documented?

---

Today is Nov 10, 4:08 AM UTC, and hitting the API today results in a refreshed quota. It does reset, but it doesn't appear to be resetting every 24 hours at 12:00 AM UTC.

Comment: I just encountered this. It was reset some time between `2015-01-31T20:02:45.579Z` and `2015-01-31T20:06:00.431Z` for me today. It's a bit hard to schedule the API requests when you don't know at what time it is reset...

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**  Evidence now suggests that the API quota rolls over at a unique time for each app.  24 hours after that app-key, plus IP, combination made its first API call.
See [this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27019800#27019800).

---

---

The quota *does* reset every 24 hours, but the time <strike>seems to wander</strike> is custom for every app-instance.  Some years ago, I seem to remember it resetting around midnight UTC, but it doesn't anymore.

Recently, [the *SmokeDetector* bot](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki) started logging when its quota reset.  Here are the logged times so far:

```
Day and Time (UTC)      Log entry
------------------      --------------
Dec 23  6:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 2001 requests remaining.
Dec 22  6:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 2014 requests remaining.
Dec 21  6:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 2851 requests remaining.
Dec 20  6:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 4665 requests remaining.
Dec 19 11:36 AM         API quota rolled over with 2580 requests remaining.
Dec 18 11:36 AM         API quota rolled over with 2824 requests remaining.
Dec 17  ???             Site + API + Bot glitch.  Rollover not certain.
Dec 16  5:06 PM         API quota rolled over with 1030 requests remaining.
Dec 15  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with  900 requests remaining.
Dec 14  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with 1896 requests remaining.
Dec 13  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with 5506 requests remaining.
Dec 12  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with 4118 requests remaining.
Dec 11  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with 2598 requests remaining.
Dec 10  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with 1640 requests remaining.
Dec  9  5:05 PM         API quota rolled over with 1624 requests remaining.
Dec  8  5:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 1981 requests remaining.
Dec  7  5:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 2866 requests remaining.
Dec  6  5:04 PM         API quota rolled over with 4596 requests remaining.
```

As you can see, the reset times tend to stay constant for a few days, then jump to a new time, then stay constant again.  A "punctuated equilibrium".
<strike>We've yet to ascertain any rhyme or reason to it.</strike>
We now know that the time changes correspond with changes to the IP/server that the app was running on.

Answer (score 1):

The information in [@BrockAdams explanation](https://stackapps.com/a/6727/83484) is useful, but needs some clarification:

##### Quota Pool

As mentioned in the [API Throttles Doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), *all* calls with an `access_token` work from a shared quota per IP.  Using multiple API `key`s will not increase or change the quota.  Only calls made with a user-based (logged-in) `access_token` create distinct pools.

More detailed information can be found in the doc on Throttles linked above.  While I have tested and confirmed that different `access_token`s have distinct pools (and that different app `key`s do **not**), I have not tested multiple-IP scenarios personally.

##### Reset time

For any given quota pool, the next reset will occur 24 hours after you made your first API call following the previous reset.

That algorithm can honestly be a bit difficult to parse in English, so some examples can be useful.  All times below can be considered either "local" or UTC -- It doesn't matter:

- **2023-12-05 at 08:00:** You start using the API and make your first call at 08:00 local time.  With an API `key` in your calls, you have a default 10,000 quota for the next 24-hours.
- You exhaust your quota within 24 hours (exactly when does not matter).
- **2023-12-06 at 07:59:**  The next day, you attempt to make an API call, and it will fail because the quota will not reset until 08:00.
- **2023-12-06 at 08:00:** The quota resets.
- **2023-12-06 at 09:00:** You make your next API call, which will succeed (based on quota).  This is now the *first API call following the previous reset.*  It will be another 24 hours until the next reset.
- You again exhaust your quota within 24 hours (exactly when does not matter).
- **2023-12-07 at 08:30:** You attempt an API call, which will fail, because the next reset won't be until 09:00.

##### Real-world Implications

Honestly, most usage is never going to need 10k calls in a 24 hour period.  A more likely scenario is that you may just be making your calls without a `key` at all.  That's completely natural when starting off with low-usage of the API.  In that case, you'll be getting the default 200 and be more aware of the decreasing quota.  Of course, you can always start using a `key` to get around that if needed.

Regardless of your quota size, *if you need it*, the biggest problem with the current implementation is that you won't know exactly when your reset is unless you keep track of that first call of the 24-hour period.