# When does API quota reset?

Tags: support, api, quota

I had a program consuming Stack Overflow API quota (10,000 per day) last night across midnight. This morning I checked, and my quota has not been set back to 10,000. Is this normal? If yes, when does API quota reset usually? I am wondering if there is anything I did wrong with my API authentication.

Comment: Found this earlier discussion from 4+ years ago: https://stackapps.com/questions/3746/why-is-my-api-quota-not-resetting-after-utc-reset – looks like the quota does not reset at a specific time. It can be any time of the day and user-specific? Will see.