# How to make a Stack Exchange API call, using my key

Tags: api-v2, api-key, support, quota

I have a Meteor application and I'm making API calls like:

```
var urlString = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/"+surl;
HTTP.call ("GET", urlString, {params:{site:"stackoverflow"}}, 
    function (error,result) {
        console.log (result.data);
    }
);
```

At present I'm getting quota-limited to 300 calls only.
But I want more than 300 and I have an application key.

How do I request, using the API key, so I can get 10,000 calls per day?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you just append your key to the URL as a parameter.
For example, looking for users 1 and 5:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1;5?site=stackoverflow&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

So, it looks like your `HTTP.call` would become:

```
HTTP.call (
    "GET", 
    urlString, 
    {params:{site:"stackoverflow", key:"YOUR_KEY_HERE"}}, 
    function (error,result) {
        console.log (result.data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thx for the answer,One issues is if the request we sent is bad, then in console it is showing bad request message(404), It is also displayinf the api_key in error message, how to overcome this.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but it sounds like a new/different problem.  Open a new question and give details.