# Do my users need to be logged in, for quota?

Tags: support, api-v2, questions, rate-limit

I am building an application and want to showcase relevant Stack Overflow questions. I have made the request and getting a response, but its responding with a quota value:

> "quota_max": 300,
>   "quota_remaining": 262

Here's my request option:

```
let options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced',
  qs:
  {
    page: '1',
    pagesize: '10',
    order: 'desc',
    sort: 'relevance',
    q: '<Some question>',
    accepted: 'True',
    site: 'stackoverflow'
  },
  headers:
  {
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

I don't want all my users to be logged into Stack Overflow. Just give them the link to forward them to the relevant question.
How do I go ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can just give them the link, and they don't need to be logged in.
The `quota` is a function of your API key (mainly).

Register your app and use a key and that will give you a 10K quota.

See:

- [**How API Keys Work**](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work).
- [Looking for a beginner's tutorial to using the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api).
- [How to make a Stack Exchange API call, using my key](https://stackapps.com/questions/4699/how-to-make-a-stack-exchange-api-call-using-my-key)

Comment: Still with API key, i have a quota of 10,000 per day. I am using it in an application, and if it hits production, there will be more hits. I did not find any clear instruction (other than "contact us") in case we want to enhance the quota.

Comment: That's all you need to do (other than build a useful app, with a good track record). There's a contact link on every page.  There's only been one app, that I know of, that genuinely needed more than 10K, and they got an increase without any problems.