# How to make unlimited requests to API

Tags: feature-request, api-key

I wanted to make unlimited call to the API to retrieve/update the threads. Is there any way to do so?

I understand
"Without a key you can make 300 requests per day, with a key you can make 10,000 requests per day
With an access token, the 10,000 request limit is just for the app for that user. *
Without an access token, the 10,000 request limit is shared between apps on the IP Address."

### Is there any exception on top of this?

Do you have Rest API which can be consumed in our application?

Comment: See ["How API Keys Work"](http://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work). ***If*** you have a legitimate need for more than 10K calls, you may contact Stack Exchange and get an increase.

Comment: Question 1 - Based on the details in the given link " If you can demonstrate a need for a higher request quota, contact us.". Please suggest whom to contact for the same purpose. Question 2 - Do you have Rest API which can be consumed in our application?