# Is the Stack API daily quota of 10,000 a hard limit, or can it be increased?

Tags: support, api, rate-limit, quota

We are developing an indexer that will be used to store and serve up questions/answers related to our products. The indexer uses a key (and soon an access_token) to retrieve the data from Stack Exchange's API.

We are currently under the 10,000 limit by running the indexer every hour; however, we would like to run it at least every 10 minutes so that our users have a real-time experience.

Is there a way that we can increase the quota or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

See [How API Keys Work](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work).  It's six years old, but a leading API developer said:

> ... If you can **demonstrate a need** for a higher request quota, [contact us](https://stackapps.com/contact).
>
> However, the Key limit should be sufficient for development, so please **only request an increased quota when your application is live and has a non-trivial number of users.**

(Emphasis and contact link added)

Update: At least one app (SmokeDetector) has done this. *Earning* a quota limit over 10K.

---

---

---

Meanwhile, you state that your app "store(s) and serve(s) up questions/answers related to our products."  It is difficult to see how this would need so much quota.

- You can get ***every*** question asked each day on Stack Overflow with only 78 API calls<sup>‡</sup>.
- Polling every 10 minutes only takes 144 API calls.
- A [certain app](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) theoretically scans every single post on *all*
  Stack Exchange sites (not all through the API though) and it only
  uses up to about 9K API calls per day.

Intelligent: caching, API filters, and use of the "Last activity" tools can really cut down on the need for API calls and allow more frequent polling of "hot" questions and answers.

---

<sup>‡</sup> There are [currently 7.8K questions asked each day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), at 100 questions returned per API call (`pagesize` set to max of 100).  Use something like [the `/questions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) with `fromdate` set to the last 24 hours.

Comment: Brock, you say "You can get every question asked each day on Stack Overflow with only 82 API calls." Can you elaborate on this or provide a source? Thanks!

Comment: @johnnyRose, see the updated answer.  (PS: Activity has dropped on SO.)

Comment: I see, that number is lower than I expected. Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.